# What are possible reasons for a p-value of 0.00 in statsmodels' multiple regression test?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels, olsmultiplelinearregression

I am doing a multiple regression test with statsmodels.
I am very confident that there is a relationship in the data, both from what I already know about this data through other sources and from plotting, but when I do a multiple regression test with statsmodels, the p-value is shown as 0.000. My interpretation of low p-values is that there is no relation. However, a value of 0.000 seems more like something has failed computationally, because I would assume that statistical noise alone would give me a low p-value of at least 0.1.
What could be the reason for a multiple regression test that computes without errors but gives a p-value of 0.000 when there is clearly a relationship in the data?

EDIT:
I am not sure if this is a statistical or a code problem. It would therefore be really helpful if people with experience woth `statsmodels` could tell me whether I used it correctly. If there is consensus about this being a data-related problem I would close this question here and reopen it on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as suggested in a comment

In the below image I have plotted the independent variable against the dependent one. I think this shows that there is *some* kind of relationship there:
[image: Plot of one of the independent variables against the dependent one]
But when I do a multiple regression test:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = df.dropna()
Y = df['share_yes']
X = df[[
    'party_percent',
]]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
ks = sm.OLS(Y, X)
ks_res = ks.fit()
ks_res.summary()
print(ks_res.summary())
```

... the p-value is shown as 0.000:

```py
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:              share_yes   R-squared:                       0.504
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.504
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     2288.
Date:                Mon, 27 Dec 2021   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        13:41:57   Log-Likelihood:                 2152.1
No. Observations:                2256   AIC:                            -4300.
Df Residuals:                    2254   BIC:                            -4289.
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
=================================================================================
                    coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const             0.4296      0.004    103.536      0.000       0.421       0.438
party_percent     1.2539      0.026     47.831      0.000       1.202       1.305
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       10.487   Durbin-Watson:                   0.931
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.005   Jarque-Bera (JB):               10.492
Skew:                          -0.166   Prob(JB):                      0.00527
Kurtosis:                       3.044   Cond. No.                         13.6
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
​
```

This is what my pandas dataframe looks like:

```py
     unique_district  party_percent      share_yes
0               1100       0.089320       0.588583
1               1101       0.099448       0.505556
2               1102       0.146040       0.545226
3               1103       0.094512       0.496875
4               1104       0.136538       0.513672
...              ...            ...            ...
2252           12622       0.040000       0.274827
2253           12623       0.038660       0.322917
2254           12624       0.016453       0.439539
2255           12625       0.060952       0.386774
2256           12626       0.032882       0.306452
```

Please note that I am actally using more than one variable, therefore *multiple* regression, but for the sake of brevity I only used one here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. General questions about probability and statistics may be suitable on our sibling site [stats.se] (but check their help pages before asking there).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am suspecting a programming error, or rather that I didn't use the package in the correct way. I'll update my question to make this clearer.

Comment: I believe it means your p-value is less than 0.0005 (suggesting you can reject the null hypothesis of a zero coefficient at alpha=0.05, for example). As a side note, it does not look like you've plotted the dependent against independent variable (x=share_yes, y=party_percentage). You've plotted them both (x1=share_yes, x2=party_percentage) against some exogenous factor, unique_district. If unique_district is a covariate you may want to decorrelate both variables with this one prior to MLR.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a programming question (aside from the possibility of a bug, which is impossible to tell without providing full dataset), I'll answer here since it's not closed yet and I don't see you asking it on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

P-values are mostly a function of sample size (which is easy enough to see, e.g. refer to chapter 7.6 of [The Truth about Linear Regression](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/TALR/TALR.pdf)) and (for nonzero parameters) approach zero in the limit (w.r.t. sample size). You have a univariate regression of decent sample size, so the p-value obtained should come as no surprise.